# Transformation of the points on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, 3d

How do I transform a point $(x,y,z)$ on plane $\Pi (ax + by + cz = 0)$ to a point $(x',y',z')$ on plane $\Phi(ax+by+cz+d=0)$?

What matrix should I use?

Here is a 2-D representation of what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Comment: There are infinitely many transformations which maps plane onto plane. Do you have any more constraints on such a transformation? Plus you notation of plane is really wierd. I would write $\Pi(x,y,z) = ax+by+cz = 0$

Comment: The vector I use for transformation should be orthogonal to the vector $<a,b,c>$

Comment: Than it is imposible. If you translate any point on plane $\Pi$ by vector orthogonal to $(a,b,c)$ you will get again point on $\Pi$. Let $n=(a,b,c)$ and $t$ translation vector orthogonal to $n$ ie $t\cdot n = 0$, than $ n\cdot (x+t) = n \cdot x$

Comment: I think you need vector parallel to $(a,b,c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Any element of the first plane is the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ \frac{-ax-by}{c} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -\frac{a}{c} \end{bmatrix}x+\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ -1 \\ -\frac{b}{c} \end{bmatrix}y$$

$$\Pi=\text{span} \left< \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -\frac{a}{c} \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ -1 \\ -\frac{b}{c} \end{bmatrix} \right>$$

Any element of the second plane is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ \frac{-ax-by-d}{c} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -\frac{a}{c} \end{bmatrix}x+\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ -1 \\ -\frac{b}{c} \end{bmatrix}y+\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -\frac{d}{c} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\Phi=\text{span} \left< \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -\frac{a}{c} \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ -1 \\ -\frac{b}{c} \end{bmatrix} \right> + \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -\frac{d}{c} \end{bmatrix} $$

Call $v_1,v_2,v_3$ the vectors involved in the last equation (which are lineary independent). Any element of the planes $\Pi$ and $\Phi$ is writed in the form:

$$v_\Pi=\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2$$
$$v_\Phi=\delta v_1 + \epsilon v_2 + v_3$$

If such transformation exists a matrix $A$ would exist with the property:

$$Av_\Pi=\alpha A v_1 + \beta  A v_2$$

$$\text{span}<Av_1,Av_2>=\text{span}<v_1,v_2>+v_3$$

Answer (score 1):

Lets use vector notation.

Denote plane $\Pi$ as $\Pi(\textbf x) = \textbf n \cdot \textbf x = 0$, where $\textbf n=(a,b,c)$, $\textbf x = (x,y,z)$, $\Phi(\textbf x) = \textbf n \cdot \textbf x + d = 0$.

Now we have point $\textbf x$ on plane $\Pi$, $\Pi(\textbf x) = 0 $. We want to translate it by vector parallel to $\textbf n$ and get point on $\Phi$. Therefore we are looking for $s$ for which $\Phi(\textbf x+s\textbf n) = 0$

$$\Phi(\textbf x+s\textbf n) = \textbf n \cdot (\textbf x + s\textbf n ) + d =\textbf n \cdot \textbf x + s \textbf n \cdot \textbf n + d = \Pi(\textbf x) + s \|\textbf n\|^2 + d =  s\|\textbf n\|^2 + d  = 0$$

so 
$$
s = - \frac{d}{\|\textbf n\|^2}
$$
Thus we need to translate point $\textbf x$ by vector $- \textbf n  \frac{d}{\|\textbf n\|^2}$.

Comment: it is dot product in $n\dfrac{d}{||n||^2}$ right? And how do I apply to a point $(x,y,z)$?

Comment: No, it is product between scalar and vector so result is vector which you can simply add to $(x,y,z)$. I marked all vector in bold to make more clear what is vector and what is scalar.

Comment: @tom what I was trying to prove is there no exists a matrix $A$ which makes the translation possible.

Comment: This only shifts the points further on the same plane. But interestingly, when I add $\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{n}\dfrac{d}{||n||^2}$, the points are both are on target plane and shifted further. Again, wrong result, but they are on the correct plane.